# React useEffect causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `useEffect` hook and few buttons which perform a specific task all the buttons are perfectly working but the clear btn is causing infinite warning.

This is the warning

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside `useEffect`, but `useEffect` either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I am creating a todo list app as I am a beginner in react i am practising this project on my own here is the code

```js
let finalArr = arr;
const [renderAgain, setRenderAgain] = useState(() => returnTodos(finalArr));
useEffect(() => {
  if (btn === "clr") {
    deleteCompleted();
  } else if (btn === "act") {
    finalArr = findUniqueElements(arr, finishArr);
  } else if (btn === "com") {
    finalArr = finishArr;
  } else {
    console.log("all");
    finalArr = arr;
  }
  const newRenderAgain = returnTodos(finalArr);
  setRenderAgain(newRenderAgain);
}, [arr, finishArr, btn]);

function deleteCompleted() {
  finalArr = findUniqueElements(arr, finishArr);
  setArr(finalArr);
  setFinishArr([]);
}
```

my GitHub repo link: https://github.com/ayussh-2/React-To-do-list

Comment: You're appear to be passing a function to `setRenderAgain()` which will be executed immediately. I'd argue that functions are not state. Use `useCallback()` if you want a memoised function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when btn === "clr", your useEffect calls deleteCompleted, which change arr and finishArr with `setArr(finalArr);` and `setFinishArr([]);`, and since arr and finishArr are dependencies in your useEffect, the useEffect will run again, and repeats infinitely.

A quick workaround is to reset btn.

```
if (btn === "clr") {
   setBtn('');
   deleteCompleted();
}
```

Also this line `const [renderAgain, setRenderAgain] = useState(() => returnTodos(finalArr));` should be `const [renderAgain, setRenderAgain] = useState(returnTodos(finalArr));` based on what you have in your useEffect

Comment: worked brilliantly! thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your useEffect seems to only depend on the state of the btn variable. Try having it as the only dependency in the useEffect Array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ..your code
}, [btn]);
```

This way it will only re-run when the btn variable changes.

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're facing with the `useEffect` hook causing an infinite loop is a common one when learning React. This happens when you have a state update inside `useEffect` that triggers the effect to run again, leading to an endless cycle. Let's break down your code and see how we can resolve this.

Firstly, it's good to understand that when you update a state variable in React, it causes the component to re-render. If this state update happens inside a `useEffect` hook without proper dependency management, it can lead to an infinite re-render loop.

In your case, the `useEffect` hook depends on `arr`, `finishArr`, and `btn`. Every time one of these dependencies changes, the effect runs. Inside the effect, you're updating a state (`setRenderAgain(newRenderAgain)`), which likely causes a change in `arr`, `finishArr`, or `btn`, thus triggering the effect again.

Here's how you can resolve this:

1. **Separate Concerns**: Split the `useEffect` into multiple effects if each button's action is independent. This way, you can better control when each effect should run.
2. **Correct Dependencies**: Make sure that the dependencies of `useEffect` are correct. It seems like the changes in `finalArr` should trigger the effect, but `finalArr` is not in the dependency array.
3. **Avoid Direct State Mutation**: Avoid directly mutating state like `finalArr = findUniqueElements(arr, finishArr);`. Instead, use setState functions. Direct mutations do not trigger re-renders correctly and can lead to unexpected behaviors.

Let's refactor your code a bit:

```js
// Assuming arr and finishArr are state variables and setArr and setFinishArr are their respective setters

useEffect(() => {
    let newFinalArr;

    if (btn === "clr") {
        newFinalArr = findUniqueElements(arr, finishArr);
        setArr(newFinalArr);
        setFinishArr([]);
    } else if (btn === "act") {
        newFinalArr = findUniqueElements(arr, finishArr);
    } else if (btn === "com") {
        newFinalArr = finishArr;
    } else {
        newFinalArr = arr;
    }

    const newRenderAgain = returnTodos(newFinalArr);
    setRenderAgain(newRenderAgain);
}, [btn]); // Only re-run the effect if btn changes
```

In this revised code:

- I've removed `arr` and `finishArr` from the dependency array of `useEffect`. This effect now only runs when `btn` changes.
- I introduced `newFinalArr` to avoid direct mutation of `finalArr`.
- The `deleteCompleted` function is refactored and its logic is included directly in the `useEffect`.

Remember, understanding how `useEffect` works and managing its dependencies correctly are key to avoiding infinite loops and other side effects in your React applications. Keep practicing, and you'll get the hang of it!